cannot access USB webcam within Raspbian OS in a VM
I have been trying to get some code that I got from github to run but I keep getting the error cannot open camera by Index.I am using opencv.I am running raspbian os on a vm. my webcam shows up on lsusb, but I cannot take pictures with it
my webcam is a "logitech c270". I am on vbox and I have webcam passthrough aswellas usb device on.
running fswebcam gives the following error
fswebcam test_image.jpg
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Adjusting resolution from 384x288 to 352x288.
--- Capturing frame...
Timed out waiting for frame!
No frames captured.

running modinfo uvcvideo gives
modinfo uvcvideo
filename:       /lib/modules/5.10.0-15-amd64/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvcvideo.ko
version:        1.1.1
license:        GPL
description:    USB Video Class driver
author:         Laurent Pinchart <laurent.pinchart@ideasonboard.com>
srcversion:     E47A6A23F7770184CE233C3
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v8086p0B03d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v29FEp4D53d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v2833p0211d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v2833p0201d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v1C4Fp3000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v1B3Fp2002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v1B3Bp2951d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v19ABp1000d00*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v19ABp1000d01[0-1]*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v19ABp1000d012[0-6]dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v199Ep8102d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v18ECp3290d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v18ECp3288d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v18ECp3188d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v18CDpCAFEd*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v1871p0516d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v1871p0306d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v17EFp480Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v17DCp0202d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp8A34d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp8A33d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp8A31d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp8A12d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp5931d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v174Fp5212d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v152Dp0310d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p5103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp0004d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0BD3p0555d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0AC8p3420d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0AC8p3410d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0AC8p332Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v06F8p300Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05E3p0505d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05C8p0403d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8600d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8501d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05A9p7670d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05A9p264Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05A9p2643d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05A9p2641d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v05A9p2640d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v058Fp3820d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v04F2pB071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp082Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C7d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C6d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C5d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C3d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C2d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v046Dp08C1d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v045Ep0723d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v045Ep0721d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v045Ep00F8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0458p706Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
alias:          usb:v0416pA91Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic0Eisc01ip00in*
depends:        videobuf2-v4l2,videodev,videobuf2-common,usb-common,usbcore,videobuf2-vmalloc,mc
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           uvcvideo
vermagic:       5.10.0-15-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Debian Secure Boot CA
sig_key:        4B:6E:F5:AB:CA:66:98:25:17:8E:05:2C:84:66:7C:CB:C0:53:1F:8C
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
signature:      25:FD:29:93:CD:F0:A2:83:71:B1:AC:99:FE:6E:D8:BA:4C:74:1B:0A:
                E8:14:96:1B:50:DA:32:B3:38:D9:25:32:07:B9:C5:09:2D:80:56:A3:
                24:CA:C6:E9:F4:29:BE:F5:46:BA:12:F2:6A:90:B8:90:DF:BB:5A:44:
                D4:DD:FF:CA:41:BA:67:C3:71:60:95:77:B5:93:71:78:97:73:3B:8F:
                DE:3E:CD:D0:36:9C:C9:0F:6D:F4:2E:16:C9:96:27:E0:A7:A3:DC:10:
                EC:32:11:4D:E7:81:B6:55:90:42:B3:50:40:12:DF:16:0F:71:1A:4F:
                D9:4E:E0:D1:38:CF:A4:2C:0B:67:B0:5B:B4:F2:76:28:F2:48:AF:FE:
                8B:A0:6B:39:81:39:F2:A9:A2:37:B9:1A:B2:48:0E:73:83:57:7E:99:
                8C:BC:BA:B3:88:EB:DE:8C:E2:7D:67:27:0A:A1:BD:15:A8:18:22:E7:
                16:E0:E9:49:B9:ED:1D:5D:37:30:AF:20:47:CF:76:13:F0:93:58:A4:
                BE:BF:35:CC:39:4B:7C:5C:F7:03:21:2F:43:FC:56:E3:11:5E:30:86:
                FE:E7:E3:93:A9:56:27:2B:18:6F:73:C0:42:E2:59:91:21:45:C1:41:
                4A:61:C3:A3:3D:17:7E:F2:2B:A4:0F:0C:4A:2A:BB:93
parm:           clock:Video buffers timestamp clock
parm:           hwtimestamps:Use hardware timestamps (uint)
parm:           nodrop:Don't drop incomplete frames (uint)
parm:           quirks:Forced device quirks (uint)
parm:           trace:Trace level bitmask (uint)
parm:           timeout:Streaming control requests timeout (uint)

I tried adding myself to video group but I am already in video group.
running v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video* --all returns
v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --all
Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Card type        : UVC Camera (046d:0825)
        Bus info         : usb-0000:00:0b.0-1
        Driver version   : 5.10.120
        Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
                Video Capture
                Metadata Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Model            : UVC Camera (046d:0825)
        Serial           : 92974950
        Bus info         : usb-0000:00:0b.0-1
        Media version    : 5.10.120
        Hardware revision: 0x00000012 (18)
        Driver version   : 5.10.120
Interface Info:
        ID               : 0x03000002
        Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
        ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
        Name             : UVC Camera (046d:0825)
        Function         : V4L2 I/O
        Flags         : default
        Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
          Link 0x02000019: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 4': Data, Enabled, Immutable
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 352/288
        Pixel Format      : 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG)
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 0
        Size Image        : 102400
        Colorspace        : sRGB
        Transfer Function : Rec. 709
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: ITU-R 601
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
        Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 352, Height 288
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 352, Height 288
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection Video Capture: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 352, Height 288, Flags:
Selection Video Capture: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 352, Height 288, Flags:
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
        Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=32 value=32
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=32 value=32
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=64 value=131
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=2
                                0: Disabled
                                1: 50 Hz
                                2: 60 Hz
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=0 max=10000 step=10 default=4000 value=1530 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=24 value=24
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=1 step=1 default=0 value=0
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
                                1: Manual Mode
                                3: Aperture Priority Mode
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=1 max=10000 step=1 default=166 value=667 flags=inactive
         exposure_auto_priority 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=1

running modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000 quirks=0x80 did nothing...
I have tried to use ffmpeg, vlc, fswebcam, guvcview...but none of them are able to access the camera.
and thats where I am...
here is the code I was trying to run:
#!/usr/bin/python3

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Display the image captured from the camera. Used as a test program to verify if OpenCV has been properly installed.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# automaticdai
# YF Robotics Labrotary
# Instagram: yfrobotics
# Twitter: @yfrobotics
# Website: https://www.yfrl.org
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

CAMERA_DEVICE_ID = 0
IMAGE_WIDTH = 320
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 240
fps = 0


def visualize_fps(image, fps: int):
    if len(np.shape(image)) < 3:
        text_color = (255, 255, 255)  # white
    else:
        text_color = (0, 255, 0)  # green
    row_size = 20  # pixels
    left_margin = 24  # pixels

    font_size = 1
    font_thickness = 1

    # Draw the FPS counter
    fps_text = 'FPS = {:.1f}'.format(fps)
    text_location = (left_margin, row_size)
    cv2.putText(image, fps_text, text_location, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                font_size, text_color, font_thickness)

    return image


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # create video capture
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(CAMERA_DEVICE_ID)

        # set resolution to 320x240 to reduce latency
        cap.set(3, IMAGE_WIDTH)
        cap.set(4, IMAGE_HEIGHT)

        # Loop to continuously get images
        while True:
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # record start time
            start_time = time.time()

            # Read the frames from a camera
            _, frame = cap.read()

            # show image
            cv2.imshow('frame', visualize_fps(frame, fps))

            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # record end time
            end_time = time.time()

            # calculate FPS
            seconds = end_time - start_time
            fps = 1.0 / seconds
            print("Estimated fps:{0:0.1f}".format(fps))

            # if key pressed is 'Esc' then exit the loop
            if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        # Clean up and exit the program
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cap.release()

code exits with error:
python3 src/camera-test/cv_camera_test.py
[ WARN:0@0.021] global cap_v4l.cpp:999 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
[ERROR:0@1.070] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:158 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
OpenCV(4.10.0) /tmp/pip-install-_8kmh5mn/opencv-contrib-python_4b0ff950cd324340b3bc4b3ae8ba9cc4/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:973: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'


I should also mention that I am totaly new to this, I dont know what any of this means. I just want to get some example code going before I order my raspberry pi...
